# How do I run an Octave code on a cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, octave

I recently set-up 5 debian-based computers with the purpose of running a series of tests to determine the effect of additional nodes on the amount of processing time. I am wondering how I should set up this cluster and how I should run the code so I can see the processing data. I have an unmanaged ethernet switch I was planning on using to connect the nodes, but is it beneficial? If I should first set up the cluster, and then run the octave code on the preexisting cluster, how do I ensure that the code runs on the whole cluster and not just the main node?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not a question about programming. Maybe it’s suited for https://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: Are you asking if octave has a 'cluster' package? If not, how do you plan on communicating data between the various processes? Octave supports sockets but other than that you'd have to handle any communication overheads yourself.